# Qual è il senso di "halle" nel libretto di Un ballo in maschera?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libretto dell'opera di Giuseppe Verdi *Un ballo in maschera*, prima dell'apparizione di Ulrica, un'indovina, un coro di donne e fanciulli canta queste parole:

> Zitti... l'incanto non dessi turbare...
>   
>   il demonio tra breve **halle** a parlare!

Non riesco a capire il senso di questo "halle". Immagino che abbia qualcosa a che vedere col verbo "avere". Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Giusto per pedanteria, l'autore del libretto, e quindi di queste parole, è Antonio Somma.

Comment: I libretti delle opere di Verdi non sono precisamente modelli di italiano. `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Letteralmente significa *le ha*, cioè *il demonio ha a parlarle* o, in un italiano un po' moderno

> Il demonio deve parlarle.

In questo caso *avere a* è una costruzione che non è sopravvissuta fino all'italiano contemporaneo (ma per esempio in francese è molto comune) e significa *dovere* (in modo simile all'inglese *to have to*).

Comment: si può dire "ho da parlarti" nel senso di "devo parlarti" ma credo sia un espressione più colloquiale che da italiano scritto.